# Como usar el split con mas datos en visual

Tags: .net, split

tengo una duda, quisiera saber como poder separar mis variables y numeros de los operadores, aqui va mi ejemplo:

```
Dim letras As String()
    Dim texto As String = "abc*5+x/(y+z)"
    letras = texto.Split(CChar("*"))
    For i = 0 To letras.Count - 1
        MsgBox(letras(i))
    Next

letras(0)=abc
letras(1)=5+x/(y+z)
```

Mi duda es como podria separarlo por cada operador que encuentre y quedara algo asi:

```
letras(0)=abc
letras(1)=5
letras(2)=x
letras(3)=y
letras(4)=z
```

Cual podria ser la mejor manera de poder hacerlo, gracias

Comment: Mira [ask] <- ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] <- ACA para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: En realidad, lo que vos queres se hace con un arbol de expresiones para que sepa que cosas separar.. o hacer un split del split del split, etc....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como bien dice @gbianchi en un comentario, parece que lo que quieres haces es un árbol de expresiones para analizar una ecuación matemática. Ese es un tema complejo que escapa al ámbito de este sitio. Pero yo voy a darte una solución para simplemente dividir una cadena usando varios separadores. Para ello, `String.Split` en una de sus sobrecargas admite un `Array` de caracteres separadores, además de una opción para eliminar las cadenas vacías que resulten de la división de la cadena. Haciendo uso de ellas, se puede conseguir el resultado que esperas en tu ejemplo:

```
Dim texto As String = "abc*5+x/(y+z)"
Dim separadores As Char() = New [Char]() {"+"c, "-"c, "*"c, "/"c, "("c, ")"c}
Dim letras As String() = texto.Split(separadores, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

Esto devuelve en letras el resultado que esperas:

```
letras(0)=abc
letras(1)=5
letras(2)=x
letras(3)=y
letras(4)=z
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me sirvio tu respuesta